# Orchard multiple language change for whole page but not content only

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I'm building a site with Orchard which need to support two languages. I've installed Culture Picker Module which allowed me to separately input 2 languages for the same content. It looks pretty nice actually. However, when I click on the translations button, it only change the content, but for other elements like menu, it still remains in English. Is there any way to change completely for the whole page? Or how to make a global button of changing the language? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on Manage Content in Administration. You have to search for widgets and then add a part. After that, you search for Localization.

Then, go to the widgets area. You can select a widget like the menu, and then you can just simply add a translation and add the translated version of your menu as the other answer proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the Localized version of your menu?